# sql trigger stopped working after 8 months (not showing up in profiler)

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, triggers

I have a simple insert trigger that stopped working last week. From my understanding permissions haven't changed. Its currently ENABLED. I have deleted it and created it again but it still doesn't work.

**PROFILER**: trigger doesn't appear at all. Seems like it never fires. Worked fine for past 8 months.

**TRUSTWORTHY** set to true

**PERMISSIONS**: Execute as owner.

**VARIABLES**: None.

**trigger code:**

```
....
FOR INSERT 

INSERT INTO  maintable (cars,boats, price) 
SELECT  DISTINCT cars,boats,price from ledgertable
```

Comment: What are the Row Reads, CPU characteristics of the `SELECT DISTINCT cars, boats, price from ledgertable`?

Comment: ledgertable is a temp table. Holds 3 rows, 3 columns. Tables it inserts into has a few hundred rows.  Cant check performance monitor or profiler for cpu usage of that trigger because it never fires (eventhough new data is being entered in)

Comment: Why is there no reference to the `inserted` pseudo-table in your trigger? Every time you insert one row, you're inserting the entire contents of `ledgertable` into `maintable`? Can you explain what you mean by "temp table", since it certainly doesn't look like one.

Comment: Its  like a staging table. Its temp table that never has more then 3 rows. It  gets dumped on during the insert trigger.

Comment: You'll need to provide information about the process that is inserting into the table (and presumably should be firing the Trigger).  Providing the code would be a big help.

Comment: @user719825 putting aside the fact you're missing it from profiler. Have you made sure the trigger actually execute? throw an exception from the trigger, or do 1/0 (divide by zero) error, anything to show that the trigger executes fine. If that's the case, your ledgertable is empty, if it's not the case, it's a DDL issue. Will get us closer to a solution...

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned, the lack of the code that is supposed to trigger this makes it difficult. Perhaps you have an `INSTEAD OF` trigger on the table as well that is hindering this trigger from going off?

Answer (score 0):

Trigger can be disabled. Try enabling the trigger and see if that does  the trick.